# Continue the execution code after a Fatal Error

Tags: php, imagick

I use imagick to create thumbnails of PDF files, but in some cases imagic returns a Fatal Error.
I am looking for a way to know when the fatal error occurs.
Something like this:

```
function MakeThumb($source) {
    if($im = new imagick($source)) {
    //Generate thumbnail
    return($thumb);
    } else {
    return 'no_thumb.png'; // then we will not tray again later.
    }
}
```

Comment: there's a reason its called fatal. Fixing the error is the appropriate action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
function MakeThumb($source) {
    try {
        //throw exception if can't create file
        if(!$im = new imagick($source) {
            throw new Exception('Count not create thumb');
        }


        //ok if got here
        return($thumb);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return 'no_thumb.png';
    }
}
```

I haven't tested it,but by using `Try Catch`, you can make it work

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: the $e variable is the exception. So you could go `die ('Thumb did not create: ' . $e->getMessage());` and that could echo out the error of `'Count not create thumb'`